# Orion Context Broker, how to enable CORS?

Tags: cors, fiware-orion

Using jQuery/AJAX, I am testing the NGSI9 registerContext operation described [here](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Register_Context_operation).

This NGSI9 operation works with the shared orion instance on 
http://orion.lab.fi-ware.eu:1026/NGSI9/registerContext
but not when I try it with my own instance of the Orion Context Broker (orion-psb-image-R3.4) .
Using my own instance, I get 405 Method not allowed, because CORS is not enabled.

How to change the Same Origin Policy on my own instance?

Answer (score 1):

Orion Context Broker doesn't include CORS related headers in the response (it has been identified as [a future working item](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/501)).

Thus, if you need CORS, you can implement it with a proxy between your client and Orion, that proxy including any CORS related header that your client may need.

**EDIT**: since version 0.22.0, orion supports CORS for GET operations with the `-corsOrigin` CLI parameter. Check [documentation about it](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html).

**EDIT2:** full CORS support including Preflight has been implemented in Orion for all NGSIv2 requests. It is now available in the master branch or in the official docker and soon in the 1.10.0 version (to be released by early December).

Comment: Answer has been edited (see EDIT2 block) to include new information about CORS support in newer Orion versions